# Javascript hide/show elements - Too much code, can it be better written?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some advice regarding my Javascript code. It works fine but I'm pretty certain that it's overworked and can/could be scaled down.

As of now I have 4 div elements (#5gb, #15gb, #30gb and #100gb) and 4 buttons. Each button triggers one of the four functions, showing one div and hiding the three others.

Is this proper done or do you have any other solution that doesn't require as much code.

Code below:

```
<script>
  function loaded() {
    document.getElementById("5gb").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("15gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("30gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("100gb").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<script>
  function ab5gb() {
    document.getElementById("5gb").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("15gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("30gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("100gb").style.display = "none";
  }

  function ab15gb() {
    document.getElementById("5gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("15gb").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("30gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("100gb").style.display = "none";
  }

  function ab30gb() {
    document.getElementById("5gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("15gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("30gb").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("100gb").style.display = "none";
  }

  function ab100gb() {
    document.getElementById("5gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("15gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("30gb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("100gb").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>

<button onclick="ab5gb()">5 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab15gb()">15 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab30gb()">30 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab100gb()">100 GB</button>
```

Comment: This should be _one_ function, that gets the ID of the element to show passed as parameter. That function would then set _all_ elements to `none` first, and then set the one passed via parameter to `block`.

Comment: While you might get an answer here, you might also consider asking in the [Code Review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is specifically for review of working code for improvements - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

By having one function and passing a parameter would be better. Something like following.

```
<script>
function loaded() {
  document.getElementById("5gb").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("15gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("30gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("100gb").style.display="none";
}

function ab(param) {
  document.getElementById("5gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("15gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("30gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("100gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(param).style.display="block";
}
</script>

<button onclick="ab('5gb')">5 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab('15gb')">15 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab('30gb')">30 GB</button>
<button onclick="ab('100gb')">100 GB</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggle method from the select element which will add and remove the class.

```
const ele = document.getElementById("5gb");
ele.classList.toggle('display-none')

//css
.display-none { display: 'none' }
```

Note - add default css as display-block

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one function instead of four:

```
<script>
function loaded(id){
  document.getElementById("5gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("15gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("30gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("100gb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
}
</script>

<button onclick="loaded(document.getElementById('5gb').id)">5 GB</button>
<button onclick="loaded(document.getElementById('15gb').id)">15 GB</button>
<button onclick="loaded(document.getElementById('30gb').id)">30 GB</button>
<button onclick="loaded(document.getElementById('100gb').id)">100 GB</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a parametrized function, and work with the built-in `hidden` API, which is a simple one-liner:

```js
const els = ['5gb','15gb','30gb','100gb'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));

function toggleDisplay(id) { for (const el of els) el.hidden = id !== el.id }
```

In HTML, you can use it like this:

```html
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('5gb')">5 GB</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('15gb')">15 GB</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('30gb')">30 GB</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('100gb')">100 GB</button>
```

Even better would be to not use inline event listeners, and instead put the `id` into a data-attribute:

```
<button data-toggle-id="5gb">5 GB</button>
<button data-toggle-id="15gb">15 GB</button>
<button data-toggle-id="30gb">30 GB</button>
<button data-toggle-id="100gb">100 GB</button>
```

And then work with a delegate listener:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.dataset.toggleId ?? toggleDisplay(event.target.dataset.toggleId);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `forEach` loop to iterate over your show/hide elements.

```html
<script>
  function show(id) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.target').forEach((target) => {
      if (target.id === id) {
        target.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
      }
    })
  }
</script>

<div class="target" id="5GB" style="display: block;">5 GB</div>
<div class="target" id="15GB" style="display: none;">15 GB</div>
<div class="target" id="30GB" style="display: none;">30 GB</div>
<div class="target" id="100GB" style="display: none;">100 GB</div>

<button onclick="show('5GB')">5 GB</button>
<button onclick="show('15GB')">15 GB</button>
<button onclick="show('30GB')">30 GB</button>
<button onclick="show('100GB')">100 GB</button>
```